# How can I create functions that handle polynomials?

Tags: python, polynomial-math, evaluate, multiplication

I have these problems about polynomials and I've spent about 4 hours on this, but I just can't get it. I'm new to Python and programming and I've tried working it out on paper, but I just don't know.

1. Write and test a Python function `negate(p)` that negates the polynomial represented by the list of its coeffeicients `p` and returns a new polynomial (represented as a list). In other words, write a function that makes the list of numbers negative.
2. Write a Python function `eval_polynomial(p, x)` that returns the value of `P(x)`, where `P` is the polynomial represented by the list of its coefficients `p`. For example, `eval_polynomial([1, 0, 3], 2)` should return 1*2^2 + 0*2 + 3 = 7. Use a single while loop.
3. Write and test a function `multiply_by_one_term(p, a, k)` that multiplies a given polynomial `p`, represented by a list of coefficients, by `ax^k` and returns the product as a new list.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me.

Comment: Fire up Python shell and try these examples here:  http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Case 2: the value returned is better said `1 * 2 ** 2 + 0 * 2 ** 1 + 3 * 2 ** 0` in python...

Comment: Adding on to @Anycorn's comment, use ipython or ipython notebook.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd recommend using `numpy.poly1d` and `numpy.polymul`, where the coefficients are *`a0*x2 + a1*x + a2`*.

For example, to represent `3*x**2 + 2*x + 1`:

```
p1 = numpy.poly1d([3,2,1])
```

And with the resulting `poly1d` object you can operate using `*`, `/` and so on...:

```
print(p1*p1)
#   4      3      2
#9 x + 12 x + 10 x + 4 x + 1
```

If you want to build your own functions, assuming that *p* contains the coefficients in order: *`a0 + a1*x + a2*x**2 + ...`*:

```
def eval_polynomial(p,x):
    return sum((a*x**i for i,a in enumerate(p)))

def multiply_by_one_term(p, a, k):
    return [0]*k + [a*i for i in p]
```

### Note

My evaluate function uses exponentials, which can be avoided with Horner's rule, as posted in another answer, which is available in Numpy's `polyval` function

Comment: I don't have enough reputation yet, but  would vote you up. I actually understood the logic behind your solutions.

Comment: @confusedstudent great that you understood this logic

Comment: This solution, while clear in its approach, is notably inefficient. Please consider using horner's rule to avoid calling an exponential in each iteration. I suppose I should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Please use Horner's Method instead!

For polynomials, you should consider [Horner's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).  Its main feature is that computing a polynomial of order N requires only N multiplies and N additions -- no exponentials:

```
def eval_polynomial(P, x):
    '''
    Compute polynomial P(x) where P is a vector of coefficients, highest
    order coefficient at P[0].  Uses Horner's Method.
    '''
    result = 0
    for coeff in P:
        result = x * result + coeff
    return result

>>> eval_poly([1, 0, 3], 2)
7
```

You can work through it by hand, or follow the link to see how it works.

Comment: Nice solution to evaluate the polynomials, could use Numpy's polyval though

Comment: numpy is great, but the OP was to write a function.  And there are many cases where you'd like to evaluate a polynomial without dragging in all of numpy.